# How to make a div move smoothly?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a page where divs containing text appear one after one, and disappear as soon as they are followed by another, using CSS transition :

on JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5kp6qdgg/9/

### HTML :

```
<body>
    Click multiple times on this button:
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Display one more div" />
    <div id="div_container"></div>
</body>
```

### CSS :

```
div#div_container {
  position: relative;
}

.log {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 50%;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    -moz-transition: all 2s;
    -ms-transition: all 2s;
    -o-transition: all 2s;
    transition: all 2s;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

### Javascript :

```
// Event listener
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
button.addEventListener ('click', oneMore);

// Spawn a div
function oneMore() {
    var div = document.getElementById("div_container");
  div.innerHTML += "<div class=log>Hello, I will soon disappear</div>";
  clear ();
}

// Clear every div except the last
function clear () {
    var logs = document.getElementsByClassName("log");
    for (x=0; x<(logs.length-1); x++) {
        var classes = logs[x].className.split(" ");
        // Only thoses not already cleared
        if (classes.length == 1) {
            logs[x].className += (" waiting");
            (function (x) {
                window.setTimeout ( function () {
                    logs[x].className += (" hidden");
                    logs[x].addEventListener("transitionend", function () { logs[x].style.display = "none" });
                    logs[x].addEventListener("webkitTransitionend", function () { logs[x].style.display = "none" });
                }, 500);
            })(x);
        }
    }
}
```

So the remaining div move up to the top, but jerkily, whereas I would like it to translate smoothly.

Does anyone knows how to do this only with CSS and pure javascript ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to change the `display` to `block` you can transition the `height`,`margin`, and `padding` so that they *hide* without taking up space. Then you do not need to do the ending `display:none` which is what is causing the sudden jerk.

Also you used `.innerHTML+=` this is inefficient and will cause all the elements to be recreated and rendered, and also makes it so you have to keep adding back the classes in `clear`.

Instead you could create an actual element, set all the appropriate attributes (class, innerText, etc) then [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) it. This way you can keep the classes and event listeners you may want to put on them without having to continually re-add them.

```js
// Event listener
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
button.addEventListener ('click', oneMore);

// Spawn a div
function oneMore() {
  var div = document.getElementById("div_container");
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.classList.add("log");
  newDiv.innerText = "Hello, I will soon disappear";
  div.appendChild(newDiv);
  if(newDiv.previousElementSibling){
    newDiv.previousElementSibling.classList.add("hidden");
  }
}
```

```css
div#div_container {
  position: relative;
}

.log {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-right: 50%;
    padding: 1px 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgba(250,0,0,0.7);
    color: #fff;
    width:190px;
    height:20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s;
    -moz-transition: all 2s;
    -ms-transition: all 2s;
    -o-transition: all 2s;
    transition: all 2s;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  height:0px;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  padding-top:0px;
  padding-bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
Click multiple times on this button:
<br />
<input type="button" value="Display one more div" />
<div id="div_container"></div>
```

It's a bit harder to hide an inline-block as even if you 0 out all the other style properties like height, margin, padding, etc the element is still going to effect the position of the other elements until `display` is set to `none`. You could do some tricks like setting display to block right before hiding it and then transitioning the previously mentioned styles, but that may again affect the positions of the other elements. Meaning when the display is set to block it will push the following elements down before transitioning.

There are other tricks you could use but they would require extra work and may affect the way you want your layout to be.

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I wished !!